# Tensorflow: Conditionally add variable scope

Tags: python, scope, tensorflow

I would like to change variable scope conditionally in tensorflow.

So for example, if `scope` is either a string or `None`:

```
if scope is None:

        a = tf.get_Variable(....)
        b = tf.get_Variable(....)
else:
    with tf.variable_scope(scope):

        a = tf.get_Variable(....)
        b = tf.get_Variable(....)
```

But I don't want to have to write the `a= ...`, `b= ...` part in double. I just want the `if ... else ...` to determine the scope and then do everything else the same from there.

Any ideas on how I could do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not specific to TensorFlow, but more of a general Python language question, just FYI. In any case, you can achieve what you want to do with a wrapper context manager as follows :

```
class cond_scope(object):
  def __init__(self, condition, contextmanager):
    self.condition = condition
    self.contextmanager = contextmanager
  def __enter__(self):
    if self.condition:
      return self.contextmanager.__enter__()
  def __exit__(self, *args):
    if self.condition:
      return self.contextmanager.__exit__(*args)

with cond_scope(scope is not None, scope):
  a = tf.get_variable(....)
  b = tf.get_variable(....)
```

**EDIT**: Fixed the code.

Comment: Thanks! That looks really cool and elegant ... but I don't know how to apply it in my context. Where does `tf.variable_scope` go?

Comment: It seems like your solution could result in `with False:` which doesnt seem to work.

Comment: I assume that what you mean is that I should have
`@contextmanager
def cond_scope(scope):
  yield tf.variable_scope(scope) if scope else False`
but that would still result in `with False:` which doesnt work.

Comment: So I just tried it as in my previous comment, and it works for `scope is None` (thanks to the contextmanager I assume) but it doesn't work when scope is a string. I get no error but my `tf`variables are not in the scope.

Comment: Sorry about the wrong code, I didn't quite test it before hitting enter. The above works.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks for @keveman for putting me on the right track. Though I couldn't make his answer work he put me on the right track: what I needed was an empty scope, thus the following works:

```
class empty_scope():
     def __init__(self):
         pass
     def __enter__(self):
         pass
     def __exit__(self, type, value, traceback):
         pass

def cond_scope(scope):
    return empty_scope() if scope is None else tf.variable_scope(scope)
```

After which I can do:

```
with cond_scope(scope):

    a = tf.get_Variable(....)
    b = tf.get_Variable(....)
```

For more on the `with` in python see:
[The Python "with" Statement by Example](http://preshing.com/20110920/the-python-with-statement-by-example/)